# MyBatis / Srping-Boot Mapper method attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (int)

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I'm using **MyBatis / Spring-Boot**

I'm learning it :)

I get this error message:

***Mapper method attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (int)***

I tried different way to write it, with the help of different advises in forum. None working

There is the code:

```
    @Select("INSERT INTO TB_Users(userId, firstName, lastName) VALUES( #{userId}, #{firstName}, #{lastName})")
    @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", keyProperty = "id", before = false, resultType = Integer.class)
    public int save(UserEntity userEntity);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to use `@Insert` instead of `@Select`. :)

Comment: Well for sure it works better like this :D         I'm going to buy some glasses       Thanks @ave